# How to update and save the data in yajra datatables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

> I'm beginners I have some learning of Laravel and jQuery but I don't know how to update and save the data in yajra datatable.
>
> This is the application.

[image]

When its approve:

[image]

Here's the Modal for edit:

[image]

Heres the Controllers:

Index:

```
public function index()
    {
        if (session('employee_sidebar') == 'Employee') {
            return Redirect::route('employee_category.index');
        } 
        if (session('password_entered')) {
            Session::flush();
            return redirect('/');
        }

        Helper::cache_all();
        if(request()->ajax()){
            return datatables()->of( Helper::cache_approve_manual() )
                ->addColumn('view', function($data){
                    $button2 = '<button type="button" name="view" id="'.$data->idx.'" class="view btn btn-info btn-sm mr-2">Edit</button>';
                    return $button2;
                })
                ->addColumn('chkbox', function($data){
                    $button = '
                    <div class="icheck-primary">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_id" id="checkbox_id'.$data->idx.'" class="chkbox" value="'.$data->idx.'">
                        <label for="checkbox_id'.$data->idx.'"></label>
                    </div>';
                    return $button;
                })
                ->rawColumns(['chkbox', 'view'])
                ->make(true);
        }
        
        return view ('admin.approve_manual.index');
    }
```

The Store:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        if (session('employee_sidebar') == 'Employee') {
            return Redirect::route('employee_category.index');
        } 
        if (session('password_entered')) {
            Session::flush();
            return redirect('/');
        }
        
        $month2 = Months::get();
        if (!$month2->isEmpty()) {
            $month = Months::latest()->first();
            if ($month->status != 'Approved') {
                return response()->json(['payroll' => 'Sorry, Payroll already generated!']);
            }
        }
        $rules = array(
            'id'    =>  'required',
        );
        $error = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
        if($error->fails())
        {
            return response()->json(['errors' => $error->errors()->all()]);
        }
        
        $user = auth()->user();
        $form_data = array(
            'approved_id'   =>  $user->id,
            'status'        =>  $request->status,
        );

        $id_list = $request->id;
        if (is_array($id_list) == false) {
            $datas = DB::table('users')
                ->select( 'ar.user_id AS user_id', 'ar.date',  'ar.category', 'ar.amount')
                ->leftJoin('attendance_requests AS ar', 'users.id', '=', 'ar.user_id')
                ->where('ar.id', '=' , $id_list)
                ->get();
                $user_id     = $datas[0]->user_id;
                $date        = $datas[0]->date;
                $category    = $datas[0]->category;
                $amount      = $datas[0]->amount;

            
            if ($category == 'Overtime') {
                $into = 'overtime';
            } 
            else if ($category == 'Extra Day') {
                $into = 'extra_day';
            }
            else if ($category == 'Holiday') {
                $into = 'holiday';
            }

            // Deduction
            else if ($category == 'Tardy') {
                $into = 'tardy';
            }
            else if ($category == 'Undertime') {
                $into = 'undertime';
            }

            // Absent is for misout employee only pag hindi nag input si employee ng datr sa time out
            else if ($category == 'Absent') {
                $into = 'absent';
            }

            if ($request->status == "Approved") {
                Salary::whereUserId( $user_id )->increment( $into , $amount );

                if ($datas[0]->category == 'Holiday') {
                    $data = DB::table('holidays')
                        ->select( 'holidays.id', 'holidays.date', 'holidays.name', 'holidays.type')
                        ->where('holidays.date', '=' , $date)
                        ->get();

                    $form_holiday = array(
                        'user_id'     =>  $user_id,
                        'approved_id' =>  auth()->user()->id,
                        'holiday_id'  =>  $data[0]->id,
                        'date'        =>  $date,
                        'name'        =>  $data[0]->name,
                        'type'        =>  $data[0]->type
                    );
                    HolidayReport::create($form_holiday);
                }
            }
            AttendanceRequest::where('id', '=', $id_list)->update($form_data);
        } 
        else {
            $count = count($id_list);
            for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) { 
                // PARA MAKUHA UNAHAN
                $firstArr = reset($id_list);
    
                // GET DATA FROM DB TO RESET AMOUNTS*****  
                $datas = DB::table('users')
                    ->select( 'ar.user_id AS user_id', 'ar.date', 'ar.category', 'ar.amount')
                    ->leftJoin('attendance_requests AS ar', 'users.id', '=', 'ar.user_id')
                    ->where('ar.id', '=' , $id_list)
                    ->get();
                $user_id     = $datas[0]->user_id;
                $date        = $datas[0]->date;
                $category    = $datas[0]->category;
                $amount      = $datas[0]->amount;
    
                
                if ($category == 'Overtime') {
                    $into = 'overtime';
                } 
                else if ($category == 'Extra Day') {
                    $into = 'extra_day';
                }
                else if ($category == 'Holiday') {
                    $into = 'holiday';
                }
                
                // Deduction
                else if ($category == 'Tardy') {
                    $into = 'tardy';
                }
                else if ($category == 'Undertime') {
                    $into = 'undertime';
                }

                
                if ($request->status == "Approved") {
                    Salary::whereUserId( $user_id )->increment( $into , $amount );

                    if ($datas[0]->category == 'Holiday') {
                        $data = DB::table('holidays')
                            ->select( 'holidays.id', 'holidays.date', 'holidays.name', 'holidays.type')
                            ->where('holidays.date', '=' , $date)
                            ->get();

                        $form_holiday = array(
                            'user_id'     =>  $user_id,
                            'approved_id' =>  auth()->user()->id,
                            'holiday_id'  =>  $data[0]->id,
                            'date'        =>  $date,
                            'name'        =>  $data[0]->name,
                            'type'        =>  $data[0]->type
                        );
                        HolidayReport::create($form_holiday);
                    }
                }
                AttendanceRequest::where('id', '=', $firstArr)->update($form_data);

                // TO DELETE FIRST ARRAY ID***
                if (($key = array_search($firstArr, $id_list)) !== false) {
                    unset($id_list[$key]);
                }
            }
        }

        Helper::cache_all();

        $reporting_to = auth()->user()->id;
        $helper = new Helper();
        event(new RequestManual($helper->check_count_timetable($reporting_to)['sum_count_timetable'], $helper->check_count_timetable($reporting_to)['count_manual'], $reporting_to));
        
        $text = "Success";
        return response()->json(['success' => $text]);
    }
```

The Edit:

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        $data = DB::table('users')
            ->select('users.emp_no', 'users.name', 'users.picture', 'ar.date', 'ar.category', 'ar.duration', 'ar.amount', 'ar.status', 'ar.request_type', 'ar.id AS idx')
            ->leftJoin('attendance_requests AS ar', 'users.id', '=', 'ar.user_id')
            ->where([
                ['ar.status', '=', 'Request'],
                ['ar.request_type', '=', 'Manual'], 
                ['ar.id', '=', $id],
            ])
            ->get();
        return response(['data' => $data]);
    }
```

jQuery ajax

```
  $("#approve_table").DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: {
                url: "{{ route('approve_manual.index') }}"
            },
            columns:[
                // { data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false },
                { data: "view", name: "view", orderable: false },
                { data: "chkbox", name: "chkbox", orderable: false },
                {
                    data: "picture",
                    name: "picture",
                    render: function(data, type, full, meta) {
                        if (data != '' || data != null) {
                            return (
                                "<img src={{ asset('storage/pictures/') }}/" +
                                data +
                                " loading='lazy' width='30' class='img-thumbnail' />"
                            );
                        } else {
                            return (
                                "<img src={{ asset('storage/pictures/blank.png') }}/" + " width='30' class='img-thumbnail' />"
                            );
                        }
                    },
                    orderable: false
                },
                { data: 'name', name: 'name' },
                { data: 'date', render: $.fn.dataTable.render.moment( 'dddd D MMMM YYYY' ) },
                { data: 'category', name: 'category' },
                // { data: 'duration', name: 'duration' },
                { data: "duration",
                    render: function(data, type, row){
                        var strings = row.duration;
                        var temp = strings.split(":")

                        for (let index = 0; index < temp.length; index++) {
                        var hr = temp[0];
                        var mins = temp[1];
                        var sec = temp[2];

                        
                        var zero = hr.charAt(0)
                        var one = hr.charAt(1)
                        var two = mins.charAt(0)
                        var three = mins.charAt(1)

                        
                        if (hr != 00 && mins != 00){
                            var time = hr + ' hr, ' +  mins + ' mins';
                        }
                        else if (hr != 00 && mins == 00){
                            if ( zero == 0 ) {
                                time = one + ' hr ';
                            }
                            else{
                                time = temp[0] + ' hr ';
                            }
                        }
                        else if (hr == 00 && mins != 00){
                            if ( two == 0 ) {
                                time = three + ' mins';
                            }
                            else{
                                time = temp[0] + ' mins';
                            }
                        }
                        else if (hr == 00 && mins == 00 && sec == 00){
                            var time = '1 Day';
                        }
                        return time;
                        }
                    }, 
                },
                { data: "amount",
                render: function(data, type, row){
                    return '₱ ' +  row.amount;
                }, 
                },
            ]
        });
```

Edit function that I try.

```
var id;
        $(document).on("click", ".view", function() {
            id = $(this).attr("id");
            $.ajax({
                url: "/admin/approve_manual/" + id + "/edit",
                dataType: "json",
                error: function (html) {
                    // console.error(html);
               
                },
                success: function(html) {
                    
                    document.getElementById("blah").src = "{{ asset('storage/pictures/') }}" + '/' + html.data[0].picture;
                    $("#approve_id").val(html.data[0].idx);
                    $("#name").text(html.data[0].name);
                    $("#emp_no").val(html.data[0].emp_no);
                    $("#date").val(html.data[0].date);
                    $("#category").val(html.data[0].category);

                    var strings = html.data[0].duration;
                    var temp = strings.split(":");
                    var hr = temp[0];
                    var mins = temp[1];
                    var sec = temp[2];
                    var zero = hr.charAt(0)
                    var one = hr.charAt(1)
                    var two = mins.charAt(0)
                    var three = mins.charAt(1)
                    
                    if (hr != 00 && mins != 00){
                        var time = hr + ' hr, ' +  mins + ' mins';
                    }
                    else if (hr != 00 && mins == 00){
                        if ( zero == 0 ) {
                            time = one + ' hr ';
                        }
                        else{
                            time = temp[0] + ' hr ';
                        }
                    }
                    else if (hr == 00 && mins != 00){
                        if ( two == 0 ) {
                            time = three + ' mins';
                        }
                        else{
                            time = temp[0] + ' mins';
                        }
                    }
                    else if (hr == 00 && mins == 00 && sec == 00){
                        var time = '1 Day';
                    }
                    $("#duration").val( time );

                    // $("#duration").val(html.data[0].duration);
                    $("#amount").val(html.data[0].amount);
                    

                    $("#approve_modal").modal("show");
                }
            });
        });
```

And here Save function for the approval Button. But from the save Button I don't know how to make

```
const save = (status, id_list) => {
            $.ajax({
                url: "{{ route('approve_manual.store') }}",
                data: {
                    "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
                    id : id_list,
                    status : status
                },
                method: "POST",
                error: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    // console.log(data);
                    
                    var html = "";
                    if (data.errors) {
                        error(data.errors);
                    }
                    if (data.payroll) {
                        check_payroll();
                        $("#approve_modal").modal("hide");
                        document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none";
                    }
                    if (data.success) {
                      
                        $("#approve_table").DataTable().ajax.reload();
                        document.getElementById("approve_for_many").removeAttribute("disabled");
                        document.getElementById("unapprove_for_many").removeAttribute("disabled");
                        document.getElementById("approve_each").removeAttribute("disabled");
                        document.getElementById("unapprove_each").removeAttribute("disabled");
                        document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none";
                        success(data.success);
                        $("#approve_modal").modal("hide");
                    }
                    $('input#checkAll2').prop('checked', false);
                    $('input#checkbox_id').prop('checked', false);
                    chkbox = []; 
                }
            });
        }

           
        });
```

Comment: On Approve action, after you get ajax success response you need to get updated data for display it. so, we need to use `draw()` method. add this line `dataTable.draw(false); // false param for data refresh on the same page` in your action's success response part. here `dataTable` is a object of datatable which created during datatable initialization during page load. for more reference see here https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw()

Comment: so much code to read :(

Comment: Where I gonna add this line? dataTable.draw(false); inside the success function? Im so sorry can you do it for me sir? @Harsh Patel

Comment: hey @JnixGutierrez see my answer. I just updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

On Approve action, after you get ajax success response you need to get updated data for display it. so, we need to use `draw()` method.

add this line `dataTable.draw(false); // false param for data refresh on the same page` in your action's success response part. here dataTable is a object of datatable which created during datatable initialization during page load. for more reference [see here](https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw())

> when you need to update data for display we need to get latest updated data So, we need to use "draw()" method.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var dataTable = $("#approve_table").DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: {
            url: "{{ route('approve_manual.index') }}"
        },
        columns:[
            // { data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false },
            { data: "view", name: "view", orderable: false },
            { data: "chkbox", name: "chkbox", orderable: false },
            {
                data: "picture",
                name: "picture",
                render: function(data, type, full, meta) {
                    if (data != '' || data != null) {
                        return (
                            "<img src={{ asset('storage/pictures/') }}/" +
                            data +
                            " loading='lazy' width='30' class='img-thumbnail' />"
                        );
                    } else {
                        return (
                            "<img src={{ asset('storage/pictures/blank.png') }}/" + " width='30' class='img-thumbnail' />"
                        );
                    }
                },
                orderable: false
            },
            { data: 'name', name: 'name' },
            { data: 'date', render: $.fn.dataTable.render.moment( 'dddd D MMMM YYYY' ) },
            { data: 'category', name: 'category' },
            // { data: 'duration', name: 'duration' },
            { data: "duration",
                render: function(data, type, row){
                    var strings = row.duration;
                    var temp = strings.split(":")

                    for (let index = 0; index < temp.length; index++) {
                    var hr = temp[0];
                    var mins = temp[1];
                    var sec = temp[2];

                    
                    var zero = hr.charAt(0)
                    var one = hr.charAt(1)
                    var two = mins.charAt(0)
                    var three = mins.charAt(1)

                    
                    if (hr != 00 && mins != 00){
                        var time = hr + ' hr, ' +  mins + ' mins';
                    }
                    else if (hr != 00 && mins == 00){
                        if ( zero == 0 ) {
                            time = one + ' hr ';
                        }
                        else{
                            time = temp[0] + ' hr ';
                        }
                    }
                    else if (hr == 00 && mins != 00){
                        if ( two == 0 ) {
                            time = three + ' mins';
                        }
                        else{
                            time = temp[0] + ' mins';
                        }
                    }
                    else if (hr == 00 && mins == 00 && sec == 00){
                        var time = '1 Day';
                    }
                    return time;
                    }
                }, 
            },
            { data: "amount",
            render: function(data, type, row){
                return '₱ ' +  row.amount;
            }, 
            },
        ]
    });


    const save = (status, id_list) => {
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{ route('approve_manual.store') }}",
            data: {
                "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
                id : id_list,
                status : status
            },
            method: "POST",
            error: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            },
            success: function(data) {
                // your logic 
                dataTable.draw(false); // false param for data refresh on the same page
            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

I added only one line in your code. see save function's ajax success part

I hope this one helps to you

---

**& I found one mistake in your code**.
we can also use `table.ajax.reload()` method **instead of draw()** method. I see in question source code. you use that ajax.reload() method.

but you did a one mistake
you can't use reload() method as like this `$("#approve_table").DataTable().ajax.reload();`

you need to use Datatable's object for call ajax.reload() method.

so as above my answer code. you need to save datatbale's object in a one variable then you need to that object variale for calling ajax.reload method

```
var approveDataTable = $("#approve_table").DataTable({
        // your other code logic
});
```

then we need to use approveDataTable variable for calling ajax.reload() method. as like below

```
approveDataTable.ajax.reload( null, false ); // user paging is not reset on reload
```

for more about ajax.reload method [see here](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload())

Comment: Thank you sir. But Sir this is for the approve Button. You can see the first picture there's a approve Button besides of Decline Button. when I click the checkbox and click the approve button. It will automatically go to the second datatable. But I want. Is to create a function for the Save Button in Modal to Edit the data in datatable. can I do that?  @Harsh Patel

Comment: yes you can do it, when you need to edit. on save button click event fire ajax request of edit the data. then on that success response just use `ajax.reload()` or `draw()` method. using this datatable will get latest records for display it.

Comment: I already done that type of flow. In my one of project. there is a many deals. then admin user will approve, decline it or edit it using datatable. & i wasn't created separte datables for approved or declined deals. I just given one dropdown menu with all, approve, pending, decline option value. when user change this option filter. at that this datatable will filter record.

Comment: It means sir we cannot create a separate store function and save function? to store it and change the data from the datatables?

Comment: you can do declare ulmitited functions in controller. its depends on our own business logics & client requirement. i just tell we can also manage display only approved, declined deals data in one datatable. we doesn't need to create separate page. but its all depens on our requirements. https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-datatables-filter-with-dropdown-exampleexample.html